# NDSolve error: Cannot solve to find an explicit formula for the derivatives. Consider using the option Method->{"EquationSimplification"->"Residual"}

Tags: differential-equations

I get the above error message when running the following code:

```
αh = 0.2; αz = 0.2; γ = 0.5; ph = 0.01; 
pf = 0.1; pE = 0.05; FC = 0.1; FE = 0.15; tC = 0.01; tE = 0; TC = 0.05; 
TE = -0.05; w = 1; ρ = 0.2; σ = 1/(1 - ρ); L = 1; RA = 0.25; μ = 1; 
G = 1; R0 = 0.1; S = 1;

v[s_] := μ Log[
    Exp[(αh ((RC[s] + 
              ph)^(-(ρ/σ))  + (αh/αz)^(-(ρ/σ)))^((
          1 - ρ)/ρ) (w + G + R0/L - (pf + tC) s - FC - 
            TC) - γ  Integrate[
           LogisticSigmoid[
             x] ((αh/αz)^(-(ρ/σ)) + (RC[x] +
                  ph)^(-(ρ/σ)) )/((RC[x] + 
                 ph)^-σ   (w + G + R0/L - (pf + tC) x - FC - 
                 TC)), {x, s, S}])/μ] + 
     Exp[(αh ((RC[s] + 
              ph)^(-(ρ/σ))  + (αh/αz)^(-(ρ/σ)))^((
          1 - ρ)/ρ) (w + G + R0/L - (pE + tE) s - FE - 
            TE) - γ  Integrate[(1 - 
              LogisticSigmoid[
               x]) ((αh/αz)^(-(ρ/σ)) + (RC[
                  x] + ph)^(-(ρ/σ)) )/((RC[x] + 
                 ph)^-σ   (w + G + R0/L - (pf + tC) x - FC - 
                 TC)), {x, s, S}])/μ]];

sol = FullSimplify[Solve[{D[v[s], s] == 0}, RC'[s]]]
solprime = Equal @@@ Flatten[sol];
solND = NDSolve[{solprime[[1]], RC[S] == RA}, RC, {s, 0, S}]
```

I have tried to add the proposed method and also Method->{"EquationSimplification"->"Solve"} but got other error messages then after quite some time of computation. 
Either "NDSolve::idelay: Initial history needs to be specified for all variables for delay-differential equations."  or "StringForm::sfr: Item 2 requested in "Delayed time `1` = `2` computed at `3` = `4` did not evaluate to a real number." out of range; 1 items available."

Any advice would be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Because you're integrating `RC[x]`, from `s` to `S = 1`, it looks like a DDE.  Try replacing the integral by `integral'[s] == -integrand, integral[S] == 0` (and making the other changes this entails).

Answer (score 3):

As Michael E2 advised we replace the integrals with differential equations, then we get a system of three equations

```
\[Alpha]h = 0.2; \[Alpha]z = 0.2; \[Gamma] = 0.5; ph = 0.01;
pf = 0.1; pE = 0.05; FC = 0.1; FE = 0.15; tC = 0.01; tE = 0; TC = 0.05;
TE = -0.05; w = 1; \[Rho] = 0.2; \[Sigma] = 
 1/(1 - \[Rho]); L = 1; RA = 0.25; \[Mu] = 1;
G = 1; R0 = 0.1; S = 1;
eq1 = g'[s] == -LogisticSigmoid[
       x] ((\[Alpha]h/\[Alpha]z)^(-(\[Rho]/\[Sigma])) + (RC[x] + 
           ph)^(-(\[Rho]/\[Sigma])))/((RC[x] + ph)^-\[Sigma] (w + G + 
          R0/L - (pf + tC) x - FC - TC)) /. x -> s;
eq2 = h'[s] == -(1 - 
        LogisticSigmoid[
         x]) ((\[Alpha]h/\[Alpha]z)^(-(\[Rho]/\[Sigma])) + (RC[x] + 
           ph)^(-(\[Rho]/\[Sigma])))/((RC[x] + ph)^-\[Sigma] (w + G + 
          R0/L - (pf + tC) x - FC - TC)) /. x -> s;
v = \[Mu] Log[
    Exp[(\[Alpha]h ((RC[s] + 
                ph)^(-(\[Rho]/\[Sigma])) + (\[Alpha]h/\[Alpha]z)^(-(\
\[Rho]/\[Sigma])))^((1 - \[Rho])/\[Rho]) (w + G + R0/L - (pf + tC) s -
             FC - TC) - \[Gamma] g[s])/\[Mu]] + 
     Exp[(\[Alpha]h ((RC[s] + 
                ph)^(-(\[Rho]/\[Sigma])) + (\[Alpha]h/\[Alpha]z)^(-(\
\[Rho]/\[Sigma])))^((1 - \[Rho])/\[Rho]) (w + G + R0/L - (pE + tE) s -
             FE - TE) - \[Gamma] h[s])/\[Mu]]];
eq3 = D[v, s] == 0;


rc = NDSolveValue[{eq1, eq2, eq3, g[S] == 0, h[S] == 0, RC[S] == RA}, 
  RC, {s, 0, S}]
Plot[rc[s], {s, 0, S}, AxesLabel -> {"s", "RC"}]
```

[image: fig1]

Comment: Thanks so much, Alex Trounev and @Michael E2. Really grateful for your help!

Comment: @WolfgangH. You're welcome!